# App force close in phone but running well in the emulator

Tags: android, togglebutton, onclicklistener

My android application running well in the emulator but when i install that app in phone and use it. It is crashed at the second activity on click of the toggle button. 
The code is below. The dob is a toggle button and start is the button from where i move on to the next activity.

```
dob.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggle clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        if (dob.isChecked()) {
            dob_player=1;
            name2.setVisibility(0);
            name3.setVisibility(1);
        } else {
            name2.setVisibility(1);
            name3.setVisibility(0);
            dob_player=0;
        }


    }
});

   start_game.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(dob_player==1){

             username1=name1.getText().toString();
             username2=name3.getText().toString();
             if(username1.equals("") || username2.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(start.this, "Enter the name of the Players", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(start.this);
                    alertbox.setMessage("Enter the name of the Players");
                    alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                // Click listener on the neutral button of alert box
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                       // mp1.stop();
                                        //mp1.release();



                }
                    });
                    alertbox.show();
          }
             else{
             Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
             bundle.putInt("qualifying",right); 
                Intent start=new Intent(start.this,game_double.class);
                start.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(start, 0);
             }
        }
        else{
            username1=name1.getText().toString();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("qualifying",right);
            Intent start=new Intent(start.this,game.class);
            start.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(start, 0);
        }

    }
});
```

My logcat is as below.

1.It comes when press the toggle button

```
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394): ERROR
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at com.ktrivia.in.start$5.onClick(start.java:129)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-10 10:52:49.453: E/ERROR(17394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

2.It comes when click on the start button

```
05-10 10:54:24.710: D/AndroidRuntime(17394): Shutting down VM
05-10 10:54:24.710: W/dalvikvm(17394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at com.ktrivia.in.start$6.onClick(start.java:150)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-10 10:54:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(17394):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The application is crashed on click of these two buttons. This is new prob for me. If anyone have any idea about this then please help me.

Comment: And can we see an exception stack trace?

Comment: provide us your log cat trace, so we could help u

Comment: where is bundle.putInt("qualifying",right); right?

Comment: My eclipse and sdk  do no show my device in the running device list when i try to run it directly in phone. So in this case how can get the lagcat of the crash point

Comment: @imrankhan right is static globle  variable which i have passed

Comment: where you have AlertDialog alertbox =builder.create(); ?

Comment: If your device is not shown in the devices list, then how are you pushing the APK to it? Try restarting adb, reconnecting phone, then pushing the apk. With the phone connected you can see the logcat in Eclipse (when adb is working properly).

Comment: @Jack i will try again to connect the device

Comment: Use the `DDMS` perspective to select the device and view the `LogCat` output.

Comment: @Jack  i have edited my question and added the logcat

Comment: What is on line 129 and 150? Its pointing you to the exact lines of code causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try using this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
```

replace start.this with CurrentActivity.this

Comment: i have added my logcat if u can help with this

Comment: hello put the complete log cat
from the line NullPointer exception to the line caused by...
all i can say is you have an objet that you don't instanciate it it's null to the compiler update your logcat so we can help you
you can switch to full screen on your logcat view and then copy/paste it

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are using Activity and intent name same so maybe causing problem.so try this:

```
AlertDialog alert  =alertbox .create(); 
alert.show();
 else{
             Intent intent=new Intent(start.this,game_double.class);
             Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
             bundle.putInt("qualifying",right); 
             intent.putExtras(bundle);
             startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
             }
        }
        else{
            username1=name1.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(start.this,game.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("qualifying",right);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
```

Comment: i have posted my log cat may be you can help me after seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),game_double.class)
```

instead of

```
    Intent start = new Intent(start.this,game.class);
```